# `Configure VPN` is grayed out and I can't configure the VPN

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

I was upgrading my system from 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS, and during the time I ran this:

```
add-apt-repository --remove ppa:seriy-pr/network-manager-l2tp
```

After upgrading, I noticed that the `Configure VPN` in network manager is grayed out and `L2TP` is not working. If I click `L2TP`, the network manager icon will suddenly disappear. I installed L2TP, and L2TP is ok now, but the `Configure VPN` is still grayed

[image]

Related logs:

```
    ~$ service network-manager status
     NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: active (running) since mer 2017-04-19 04:15:38 CST; 11min ago
         Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
     Main PID: 865 (NetworkManager)
       CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
               ├─ 865 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
               ├─1362 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /var/run/dhclient-wlan0.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/d   
               └─1373 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pi

    apr 19 04:16:15 mylaptop NetworkManager[865]: Connection terminated.
    apr 19 04:16:15 mylaptop pppd[2651]: Modem hangup 
    apr 19 04:16:15 mylaptop pppd[2651]: Connection terminated.
    apr 19 04:16:15 mylaptop NetworkManager[865]: ** Message: Terminated ppp daemon with PID 2651.
    apr 19 04:16:15 mylaptop NetworkManager[865]: <error> [1492546575.2128] platform-linux: do-change-link[4]: failure changing link: failure 19 (N
    apr 19 04:16:15 mylaptop NetworkManager[865]: <warn>  [1492546575.2128] device (ppp0): failed to disable userspace IPv6LL address handling 
    apr 19 04:16:15 mylaptop NetworkManager[865]: <info>  [1492546575.2149] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
    apr 19 04:16:15 mylaptop NetworkManager[865]: <info>  [1492546575.2150] vpn-connection[0x11b6210,1037a4fd-8d22-430a-a8d5-8f31c5bdd70b,"fast235"
    apr 19 04:16:15 mylaptop NetworkManager[865]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 1 / phase 'dead'
    apr 19 04:16:15 mylaptop NetworkManager[865]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (nm_exit_notify): cleaning up
```